# Estimate unknown sum of iid random variables

Tags: maximum-likelihood, random-variable, sample-size, small-sample, iid

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed discrete random variables with common mass function $f_X(x)$ defined for when $x \in \{0,1,\dots,N\}$ and $N$ is known.

I know the form of $f_X(x)$ (I can computationally compute this mass over the range).

Now define $S = \sum_{i=1}^{M} X_i$ to be the sum of these random variables taking values in the set $\{0,1,\dots,NM\}$.

The problem that I have is that I observe a single realisation of $S$, where $M$ is the unknown parameter. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can estimate $M$? The method of moments estimator may be too biased in this setting.

The idea I had was to try to compute the mass function for $S$ using $M$ convolutions but am not sure if this blows up computationally as $N,M$ increase. From this, I think I can search to find the $M$ which gives the likelihood its highest value, but again I believe this will run into computational issues. To make this more precise, typically $N \approx 10^4$ and $10^2 \leq M \leq 10^4$.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "$M$-sum" and "state space"?  According to your notation, the former is simply the sum of the first $M$ variables.  "State space" has no evident meaning.  Do you intend simply to mean  that the sum of $M$ random variables with values in $\{0,\ldots, N\}$ has values in $\{0,\ldots, MN\}$?

Comment: $M$-sum is indeed the sum of the first $M$ variables. And yeah, the state space of $S$ is all the possible values it can take, which in this context is $\{0,1,\dots,MN\}$. But I'll change this if it's that confusing.

Comment: Others might be fine with it.  I was concerned because those references to "$M$-sum" and "state space" suggested you might have some unusual meanings in mind.  BTW, your approach makes sense.  I don't think you face  significant computational issues, especially if you use the fft for convolution.  Moreover, you can effectively begin your search near an $M$ determined simply by comparing means: $S$ divided by the mean of $f_X$ estimates $M.$  (This is the simplest method of moments estimator).

Comment: If you know the mean & variance of $X_i$, perhaps you could utilize the Central Limit Theorem to obtain an approximate distribution of $S$? If $M$ is truly as massive as you say, this would be a pretty good approximation.